# ASP Web project doesn't run after installing Web Tools and ASP 5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I installed updates for VS2015 for ASP 5 and the web framework tools and now my regular ASP 4.6 web site won't run in debug.  It starts to run, but the browser just sits there loading.  This project runs perfectly fine on my non-updated machine.  I've even uninstalled VS and re-installed but have the same problem. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried put in a debug in application_start, to make sure that it's not because of your application rather than VS2015 and ASP, since you say that "It starts to run, but the brower just sits there loading"

Comment: As I stated, the project runs on my other machine with VS2015 that has not been updated.  And yes, I put a breakpoint in Global.asax but it never hits.